# Ajax file uploading library

Tags: library, ruby-on-rails, uploader, ajax

I am looking for a very lightweight library for uploading files asynchronously.

It is for a Rails project being updated to Rails 5.

dropzone.js was tried and sort of worked, but there was no way to tell it the upload is complete, plus the documentation sucks beyond words.

Remotipart is broken in Rails 5. It uploads fine but triggers the controller to respond to the browser which than causes a header already sent error when I try to send custom data back to the browser.

When I mean lightweight, I mean I don't care about progress bars, or any fluffery like drag and drop. Not relying on jQuery is a huge plus. Too often, jQuery plugins break when Rails updates jQuery so I avoid them like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it matches your "light" criteria - but it is jQuery free ;)

> http://fineuploader.com/

Please report back if it doesn't match

Comment: It is certainly not light, and the licensing is not optimal but this is for a non-commercial app so I will play around with it. Thanks If you know any others, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for this one sucks, but I have a small javascript only file uploader which I wrote and use: https://github.com/gabe3886/charon

It uses basic file upload fields but you can work additional functionality in as needed with the callbacks on the [XMLHttpRequest events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)